# Changing Shell to /bin/bash without root access via file

Tags: bash, shell, non-root-user

lets assume I am user(**with no rights**) and I need to change my shell as a default to /bin/bash by editing a file. So where I can find a file for a specific user where I can edit my default shell and set it permanently without involving an administrator.

And also, is there any command to change my own shell on top of that I can edit in the file directly.

I have tried to find something, but is only telling commands and files only if you have root access.

Thank you.

Comment: lets assume your default shell is tcsh and your account is properly set up. You have a `.tcshrc` file in your home directory. As the first line in this file you place the command `/bin/bash`. As soon as it hits, you will have a bash shell.

Comment: other have answer, but just for information, the file to edit is `/etc/passwd`, but `chsh` will do it for you. you ay also use `chfn` to change information about current user.

Comment: @Archemar No, the right way to change the shell is `chsh`. `/etc/passwd` is where the shell setting is stored, but only if the account is a local one, and not on all Unix variants (most if not all provide the information in `/etc/passwd`, but it might be generated from some other file), and even if that's the place where the setting is stored you shouldn't edit it manually.

Answer (score 6):

You don't need root access to change your own shell to any shell listed in `/etc/shells`.

Just run `chsh -s /bin/bash`.

A normal user can only change their own shell.  And only to one of the shells listed in `/etc/shells`.  Root can change any user's shell to anything at all.

see `man chsh` for details.

NOTE: root may disable this if they choose, e.g. by removing the setuid bit on `/usr/bin/chsh` or by listing only one or two shells in `/etc/shells`.  There's little point in doing this, however, because (as MelBursian points out in his comment) the user can always run `exec bash` in the .rc or .profile file for their current shell.  or just type `exec bash` as their first command when they login.